# Text content copy works wrongly after rendering Pdf using SVG

Tags: javascript, html, pdf.js, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I have tried to generate an app which gets pdf blob and shows it on the screen using pdfjs lib.
I works correctly but when i try to copy the text content, it gets unrelated data.

When i copy the text, it copies it as .
You can check it as below image

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TSto.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBPIU.png)

The Code i used is below

```html
<div id="the-svg"></div>
```

```js
// Asynchronous download PDF
PDFJS.getDocument(url)
  .then(function(pdf) {
    return pdf.getPage(1);
  }).then(function(page) {

  // Set scale (zoom) level
  var scale = 1.5;

  // Get viewport (dimensions)
  var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

  // Get div#the-svg
  var container = document.getElementById('the-svg');

  // Set dimensions
  container.style.width = viewport.width + 'px';
  container.style.height = viewport.height + 'px';

  // SVG rendering by PDF.js
  page.getOperatorList()
    .then(function (opList) {
      var svgGfx = new PDFJS.SVGGraphics(page.commonObjs, page.objs);
      return svgGfx.getSVG(opList, viewport);
    })
    .then(function (svg) {
      container.appendChild(svg);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

For accuracy of appearance, in showText(glyphs) function for svg, pdf.js renders a font character with glyphs **glyph.fontChar**, that is not readable on common computer. If you replace it by **glyph.unicode**, your text becomes copiable, but the PDF rendered will be a little different in appearance.

Please see pdf.js file. First make a copy of pdf.js, then modify it by commenting to test:

```
    //const character = glyph.fontChar;
```

And add line:

```
    const character = glyph.unicode;
```